# Getting rid of pop-up window when making OpenCV videos

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I've been making video flipbooks by putting together individual frames of PNG files.  At first I was using FFMPEG.  I just got OpenCV working.

However, every time I make one, I have to manually choose the encoder to use.
The window has the title: Video Compression.  The about box says it's Intel Indeo Video iYUV 2.0

Can I specify this somewhere in a Python call to OpenCV so I don't have to choose every time?

Here is the code that is making the video. Note I'm resizing the frames as they were different sized source frames.

```js
    video = cv.VideoWriter(outfile, -1, 30, (width, height), False)

    for image in images:
        cvimage = cv.imread(os.path.join(png_working_folder, image))
        resized = cv.resize(cvimage, (800,800))
        video.write(resized)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution.

I wasn't using `fourcc` previously.  Adding it to my call got me over this hump.

```
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
video = cv.VideoWriter(outfile, fourcc, 30, (width, height))
```

Adding the fourcc to the call was the key.